# Plot Wiener Process and its running maximum

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to plot a Wiener process $B=(B_{t})_{t≥0}$ and its running maximum $S_{1}=\max_{0\leq t\leq1}B_{t}$ on Mathematica. Can anybody help? I only know how to generate a Wiener process using RandomFunction, but I have no idea how to plot its running maximum.

thank you! any help is appreciated

edit:
Thank you for the answers! 
How do I plot the reflected process $S-B$ ? Is there a command that given the two graphs, outputs their difference?

Comment: Well, okay, show us what you have made so far :)

Comment: You could try using `FoldList[Max, ....` over the list of values generated with `RandomFunction`

Comment: ListLinePlot[RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 1, 0.01}], 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]

I get the Wiener Process with this.

Answer (score 5):

It is always nice to have alternative solutions. The following sets up a function which holds its value until a larger value is presented to it.

```
rMax[ts_] :=
 Block[{max = -\[Infinity], rmax},
      rmax[x_ /; x <= max]:= max;
      rmax[x_]:= (max = x; x);
      rmax /@ ts
 ]
```

Lets generate some data and extract out the states.

```
SeedRandom[1321];
s = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[], {0, 1, .001}]["PathStates"];
```

for convenience, since the data runs from zero to one, we can set the `DataRange` rather than constructing ordered pairs.

```
ListLinePlot[{s, rMax[s]}, DataRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Hopefully there will be some helper functions for working with `TemporalData` in future versions of M that will make all of this easier!

Comment: Thank you! can you see if you can help with the edit to my question? I kind of answered myself by doing: ListLinePlot[{s, rMax[s], rMax[s] - s}, DataRange -> {0, 1}]. Is that alright?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4):

```
Module[{s=4},
  Show[
  ListLinePlot[{SeedRandom[s];RandomFunction[WienerProcess[],{0,1,0.01}]},AxesOrigin->{0,0}],
  ListLinePlot[{SeedRandom[s];Apply[Transpose[{#1,FoldList[Max,First[#2],Rest[#2]]}]&,
    Transpose[First[Normal[RandomFunction[WienerProcess[],{0,1,0.01}]]]]]},AxesOrigin->{0,0}]]]
```

Some, ahem, fannying around with First[Normal... to dig out the actual time series pairs is required.

Comment: Thank you very much, the result is exactly what I wanted. I'm a very beginner with mathematica but needed to implement my school project with graphs. The code you wrote looks very complicated, I thought it would have been easier ^^, anyway thank you! it looks like I will have to spend a lot of time on this..